# Is this oauth authentication method safe?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing an OAuth secured API, and I assign each client a consumer key and secret.  I don't want to assign a separate API key for clients and me to have to keep track of.  I'm thinking that authentication happens like this: they generate their payload and sign it with their key and secret, and transmit the key.

On the server, I store the client secret, keyed by their key.  When I receive the payload, I use their key to look up the secret, then I decode the payload with that secret.  So the secret is not transmitted, but the key is.

So my question is: is this a safe way to handle this situation, or am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about how a client authenticates to the authorization server, OAuth 2.0 requires that the endpoint is secured with TLS, so recommends just using [Basic authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3).

Comment: I thought that TLS was only a recommendation, not a requirement.  But say I have to do this over plain HTTP for some reason.  Then maybe it's not quite OAuth 2.0 compliant, but is this particular protocol safe anyway?  What vulnerabilities would I be missing here?

Comment: Your client wouldn't know it was talking to the genuine authorization server, for one.

Comment: I can see how that might be bad for the client, if the request went to the wrong place.  But is there any way a rogue client can hurt **me**?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you mean by "me" in this context - your question makes it sound like you are building an OAuth implementation (including an authorization server). If you were only signing requests, you'd also need protection against replaying of another clients requests for one thing, but it's generally a bad idea to take a "roll your own" approach to these things unless you're just doing it for fun.

Comment: You might also find the [OAuth 2.0 Threat Model](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819) RFC useful.

Comment: I am talking about the authorization server, and I actually do have an OAuth toolkit that I'm using.  I'm just trying to make sure that my workflow doesn't sit on top of OAuth and undermine it in some way.